# java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 30313031

Tags: java, hibernate, gis, postgis

This relates to  [Hibernate: Could not deserialize - invalid stream header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23049498/hibernate-could-not-deserialize-invalid-stream-header).

I could not make real use of the answers so I am creating this again (and maybe things have changed a bit).

I am building a SpringBoot application and here are the libraries I use.

```
org.springframework.boot:1.5.4.RELEASE
hibernate-core:5.0.12
hibernate-spatial
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0
postgis-jdbc:2.2.1
postgresql:42.1.4
```

The code for declaring my entity

```
package be.naturalsciences.tiles.model;

/**
 *
 * @author michel
 */

import org.postgis.Point;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import javax.persistence.Basic;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

@Entity
@Table(schema = "idod", name = "coordinates")
@XmlRootElement
public class SCoordinates {
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "theid")
    public Integer id;

@Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "latitude")
    public BigDecimal latitude;

@Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "longitude")
    public BigDecimal longitude;

@Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "geometry", name="geometry")
    public Point point;
}
```

I am accessing my entity through a simple enough Repository object.

```
package be.naturalsciences.tiles.services;

/**
 *
 * @author michel
 */

import be.naturalsciences.tiles.model.SCoordinates;
import java.io.Serializable;
import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;

public interface SCoordinatesRepository extends Repository<SCoordinates, Integer>{
   SCoordinates findById(Integer id);
}
```

But I do get this `java.io.StreamCorruptedException` Exception (I did shortened it though)

```
2018-02-23 09:59:13,411 INFO  [be.naturalsciences.tiles.controllers.SCoordinatesController] (default task-2) Entering SCoordinatesController.findById()
2018-02-23 09:59:13,413 INFO  [be.naturalsciences.tiles.services.SCoordinatesServiceImpl] (default task-2) Start of SCoordinatesServiceImpl.findById(), parameter is : 2282
2018-02-23 09:59:13,436 DEBUG [org.hibernate.SQL] (default task-2) 
    select
        scoordinat0_.theid as theid1_0_,
        scoordinat0_.latitude as latitude4_0_,
        scoordinat0_.longitude as longitud5_0_,
        scoordinat0_.geometry as geometry7_0_ 
    from
        idod.coordinates scoordinat0_ 
    where
        scoordinat0_.theid=?
2018-02-23 09:59:13,608 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter] (default task-2) Forwarding to error page from request [/scoordinates/2282] due to exception [could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize]: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:333)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:488)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.findById(Unknown Source)
    at be.naturalsciences.tiles.services.SCoordinatesServiceImpl.findById(SCoordinatesServiceImpl.java:25)
    at be.naturalsciences.tiles.controllers.SCoordinatesController.findById(SCoordinatesController.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:115)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:287)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:238)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:300)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2790)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1729)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1655)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1544)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:727)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:501)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1326)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:529)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:206)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:85)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:116)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:106)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:483)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 103 more
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 30313031
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:863)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:218)
    ... 147 more
```

Any help, advice, pointers will be appreciated.

Oh, BTW I did try to use

```
com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry;
```

or

```
org.geolatte.geom.Point;
```

as alternatives but without any success, I still get the same error.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same exception thrown when I migrated my spring-boot app from spring-boot-2.1.x -> spring-boot-2.2.x

With the spring-boot-2.2.x the hibernate version has changed 5.3.x -> 5.4.x and the [hibernate-5.4 migration guide](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/migration-guide.adoc#hibernate-spatial-depends-on-jts-116) says that the JTS that hibernate-spatial depends on has migrated as well which also implied changes in package naming i.e. `com.vividsolutions.jts.*` has changed to `org.locationtech.jts.*`.

In my particular case the DAO entity that was being fetched from the database used the following imports

```
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.PrecisionModel;
```

which I had to change to

```
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.PrecisionModel;
```

which in turn was possible after changing the version of the `h2gis` dependency from

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.orbisgis</groupId>
  <artifactId>h2gis</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.orbisgis</groupId>
  <artifactId>h2gis</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Just encountered the same problem - upgrading JTS and changing out the package names fixed it for us.

Comment: With 1.5.0 I always got "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.locationtech.jts.geom.CoordinateXY", but it's working with 1.4.0.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and added below line to application.properties then it works.

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
```

You can also see the similar issue here: [How to deserialize / serialize type Geometry in spring boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56861600/how-to-deserialize-serialize-type-geometry-in-spring-boot/59623377#59623377)

Answer (score 2):

`30313031` is hex for 0101. This is not serialized data, it is ASCII text. You didn't serialize it, so you can't deserialize it either.

Comment: ... Ok ..., but this is just the way it is stored in the PostGis database I am talking to so it's a bit surprising. I mean. I entered the coordinates in the database as separate columns then used PostGis functionnalities to fill a geometry field in the DB. Nothing peculiar .... But I will look at it through simple JDBC and see what turns out. Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem today. I got `"java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 54656D70"` too, but in my case it was for String variable. It took me huge amount of time to figure it out that IntelliJ IDEA imported class:

```
import com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations.String;
```

instead of plain `java.lang.String` and that is why application could not deserialize it.

Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons could be that you did not include all related dependencies for **spring-boot-starter-data-jpa** make sure that for the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

You have included the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-digester3</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-java8 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well this was a dependency hell problem with classloaders giving back misleading information.

Thanks to a number of posts by

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126380/arturo-volpe

and

https://stackoverflow.com/users/4492890/maverick-java

I finally found my way out of it
Check out their posts, they help a lot.

BTW if it's of interest to anyone my new gradle build to get out of this hell looks like this

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '1.5.9.RELEASE' // Yeah I changed Spring version too ...
    id 'net.ltgt.apt' version '0.14'
}

description="TILES project"

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenLocal() // I had to put the oracle jar in there
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation('dom4j:dom4j:1.6') {
        force = true
    }
    implementation('org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.1') {
        force = true
    }
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.11',
            'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25',
            'org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.7.2',
            'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.5.1.RELEASE',
            'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator',
            'org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:5.0.2.Final',
            'org.apache.commons:commons-dbcp2:2.2.0',
            'com.vividsolutions:jts-core:1.14.0' 

implementation(
        'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:1.4.5.RELEASE'
    ) {
        exclude module: 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    }

implementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
        exclude module: 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    }

implementation ('org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.10.Final') {
        exclude module: 'dom4j:dom4j'
    }

implementation ('org.hibernate:hibernate-spatial:5.0.12.Final') {
        exclude module: 'postgresql'
    }

providedCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat', 
                    'org.postgresql:postgresql',
                    'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api',
                    'dom4j:dom4j',
                    'javax.servlet:jstl'
}
```

Hope this can help anyone ...

Comment: thanks, I was having a different problem but this reminded me that I needed to exclude the postgresql driver jar from my hibernate-spatial dependency because I have that jar set up in the Tomcat /lib classpath instead of via maven!

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the `hibernate-spatial` dependency to your project and have you specified `PostgisPG95Dialect` as hibernate dialect (in Spring Boot it is `spring.jpa.database-platform` property)? It should help.