# How to deserialize / serialize type Geometry in spring boot?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, geometry, json-deserialization

I have an entity with attributes of type MultiPolygon and Point; so I'm making a get request but this is returning a SerializationException.

I researched it and saw that I have to put some notes, create a configuration class and put the corresponding dependency in pom.xml. Follow as I did below:

Entity:

```
package com.zxventures.model;

@Entity
@Table(name = "pdv")
public class PDV implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 @Column(name="coverage_area")
 @JsonSerialize(using = GeometrySerializer.class)
 @JsonDeserialize(contentUsing = GeometryDeserializer.class)
 private MultiPolygon coverageArea;

 @Column(name="address")
 @JsonSerialize(using = GeometrySerializer.class)
 @JsonDeserialize(contentUsing = GeometryDeserializer.class)
 private Point address;
}
```

Config class:

```
package com.zxventures.config;

@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {

 @Bean
 public JtsModule jtsModule() {
  return new JtsModule();
 }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.bedatadriven</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-datatype-jts</artifactId>
<version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

The exception occurs:

```
could not deserialize; nested exception is 
org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
```

I think I'm missing some code but I can not detect it; I think I put all the code I saw in similar questions.

Comment: What's the rest of the exception say?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas
         Request processing failed; nested exception is 
         org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not deserialize; 
         nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not 
         deserialize] with root cause
         java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 00000000

Comment: You seem to be confusing Java serialization and JSON serialization.

Comment: @chrylis No, I'm not confusing; the error only happens when I deserialize those specific type of fields ... when I omit them, it works perfectly ... this is not the problem.

Comment: Jackson has nothing whatsoever to do with the sort of serialization in your error messages.

Comment: @philabreu I'm having the same problem. Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using Spatial data types, so need to include below dependency to work

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And change dialect accordingly e.g. `org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQL56InnoDBSpatialDialect`

See [Spatial data types](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/chapters/query/spatial/Spatial.html)

Comment: When I put these snippets, I now get a
           `java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 00000000`
I researched, but I did not find any solution for spatial type.

Comment: Bingo! Along with what you said, I had to change
    `import org.geojson.MultiPolygon; import org.geojson.Point;`
per
    `import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.MultiPolygon;
     import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point;`

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and added below line to application.properties then it works.

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
```